# Trying to pull Retail azure price

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-devops

I am trying to pull Azure Retail Prices using this link but its giving me this error can you please guide me what to do.

I don't want to apply any filter in link.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
# Call the Azure Retail Prices API
response = requests.get("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices")
#response = http.request("GET", "https://example.com/", retries=Retry(10))
# Set your file location and filename to save your json and excel file
#filelocation = r'Folderpath'
filename = 'azureretailprices_vm_scus'

# Create an array to store price list
priceitems= []
#Add the retail prices returned in the API response to a list
for i in response.json()['Items']:
    priceitems.append(i) 

print(response.json()["NextPageLink"])

# Retrieve price list from all available pages until there is no 'NextPageLink' available to retrieve prices
# Retrieve price list from all available pages until there is a 'NextPageLink' available to retrieve prices
while response.json()["NextPageLink"] != None:   
    for i in response.json()['Items']:
        priceitems.append(i) 
    response = requests.get(response.json()["NextPageLink"])
    print(response.json()["NextPageLink"])

# Retrieve price list from the last page when there is no "NextPageLink" available to retrieve prices
if response.json()["NextPageLink"] == None:
    for i in response.json()['Items']:
        priceitems.append(i) 

# Write the price list to a json file
with open(os.path.join('folder',filename) + '.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(priceitems, f)
# Open the price list json file and load into a variable
with open(os.path.join('folder',filename) + '.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    raw = json.loads(f.read())
# Convert the price list into a data frame
df = pd.json_normalize(raw)
# Save the data frame as an excel file
df.to_excel(os.path.join('folder',filename) + '.xlsx', sheet_name='RetailPrices', index=False)
```

**ScreenShot of the error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The error is due the version of  `pyOpenSSL` So, try to change the version to latest  i.e,

- uninstall the previous version of `pyOpenSSL` and
- install the latest version of `pyOpenSSL-21.2.0` (the latest version).